# How to implement shadow around triangle with IE9 support?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9

I got to make a block like that.

[image: design]

Is there a way how to apply box-shadow for the block without shadows overlapping?

Here is my the best result - http://codepen.io/To_wave/pen/zwwqRd

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="triangle"></div>
</div>

body {
  background: #F8F8F8;
  padding: 50px;
}

.box {
  height: 150px;
  background: #FFF;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(62, 62, 62, 0.2);
}

.triangle {
  width: 14px;
  height: 26px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -13px;
  bottom: -4px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.triangle:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 18px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #fff;
  transform: skew(-26deg);
  bottom: 4px;
  left: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 0px rgba(62, 62, 62, 0.2);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**to_wave**.

I create this bubble box using only one div and a different concept on the triangle to avoid this shadow box issue. Its not the perfect solution, but it works: https://jsfiddle.net/DiogoBernardelli/028wqpee/1/

What i made was create this `m-bubble::before` with `width: calc(100% + 7px)` (the calc is because the `left:-7px` positioning), and adding a `bottom:-3px`. That way, this element will fill the entire bottom of the bubble and you will avoid the shadows overlapping.

I used *`perspective`*, *`rotateX`* and *`transform-origin`* to create this "one side skewed" element. If you have a better solution to do it, fill free to make your own adjustments.

Hope it works for you, and sorry about my english.

Best regards from Brazil.

Comment: That approach has problem on scale the box;

I improved my initial idea. It looks pretty complex, but works

https://codepen.io/To_wave/pen/wddZxX

Comment: Your solution has improved, i agree. You can now remove the "bubble"  div. Congratz for the result.

Answer (score 0):

What about using canvas?

https://codepen.io/partypete25/pen/bWWLzN

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
<script>
      var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

      // begin custom shape
      context.beginPath();
      context.moveTo(20,20);
      context.lineTo(500,20);
      context.lineTo(500,300);
      context.lineTo(10,300);
      context.lineTo(20,280);

      // complete custom shape
      context.closePath();
      context.lineWidth = 5;

      context.shadowBlur=10;
      context.shadowColor="black";

      context.fillStyle = '#fff';
      context.fill();
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I improved my initial idea.
It looks pretty complex, but works [codepen.io](http://codepen.io/To_wave/pen/wddZxX)

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>


body {
  background-color: #F8F8F8;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 2px;
}

.wrapper::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  right: 2px;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: calc(100% - 5px);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 1px rgba(62, 62, 62, .2);
  z-index: -1;
}

.container {
  padding: 1px 0 8px 30px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  height: 120px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(62, 62, 62, .2);
}

.box::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  height: 26px;
  width: calc(100% + 12px);
  left: -6px;
  bottom: -5px;
  transform: skewX(-26deg);
  box-shadow: -1px 3px 4px -2px rgba(62, 62, 62, .2)
}
```